# linux redhat + change time from UTC to GMT+X

Tags: linux, rhel, date, time, timezone

how to change the time from UTC to GMT+2

my current date is UTC as the following

```
20:23:48 root@linux-test01:~ # date
Sat Apr 16 20:23:52 UTC 2016
```

and I want to change it from UTC to GMT+2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried so far ?  Setting `/etc/sysconfig/clock` and doing the localtime symlink should address this, e.g. https://thornelabs.net/2013/04/25/rhel-6-manually-change-time-zone.html